# QField/QGIS synchronization problem

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

Using QGIS 3.38.4 (LTR) and QField 2.6.3, I've been having a problem getting one project to synchronize properly by cable (another one I checked seemed fine), one symptom of which is the following Python error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\QGIS\Projects\Path_Bds\Data\observations_on_db.gpkg-shm'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/Avery/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\gui\synchronize_dialog.py", line 63, in
> lambda: self.start_synchronization()
> File "C:\Users/Avery/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\gui\synchronize_dialog.py", line 160, in start_synchronization
> copy_attachments(
> File "C:\Users/Avery/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qfieldsync\libqfieldsync\utils\file_utils.py", line 147, in copy_attachments
> shutil.copyfile(filename, dest_filename)
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~2.4\apps\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
> with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\QGIS\Projects\Path_Bds\Data\observations_on_db.gpkg-shm'

The Invalid argument line at the end would appear to be a clue is to what is happening, but I don't know enough to interpret it.

In the QGIS project folder, the observations_on_db.gpkg-shm and -wal files exist, but the ones for another .gpkg file do not, while both exist in the folder I'm trying to import from, whose contents
look like this:

[image]

But I don't always get the python error; sometimes things seem to run fine, but the .shm and .wal files for observation_on_db get left in the project directory, and the updates don't happen.  My guess is that something is going wrong with that file that prevents the updating from working properly.
This project was working fine about a week ago, but not any more, so I suspect that some kind of corruption has set in, and wonder how to identify and remove it, or maybe something completely different is going on (I have checked many times, the layers which should be editable in QField are all set of 'offline edit', and also that the observations_on layer exists and loads into the attribute table viewer in both the main project and the qfield import version of the project).

Is there perhaps some way to create from a _qfield.qgs version of a project a skeleton .qgz version that the _qfield.qgs can be synchronized to?

Comment: So what I did was rebuild the project from the data files of the old, copying styles, etc.  Maybe faster than trying to find the bug.